# idea about project in html

Tags: html, css3pie

The general idea of the project as desired
1- The project consists of more than two pages
2- It contains html5-and-css3
3-Need to contain a page that contains a form that is relevant to your project (Example: if your project is a car show, the form can contain customer data or his choice of the car in the exhibition or so)
4 - It is not permissible to use the tables in designing pages except in cases where you need to use a table (use the div tag or semantic elements in html 5)
5- The student is free to use any extras outside of what we have studied in other languages and programs to support his project

Comment: What do you need to know? I mean what is your question really ?

Comment: StackOverflow is for specific questions. BTW, never mention the word "homework" or "student".  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Make something like amazon, but with no backend, just the design